# predict the output for this pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the below program. how does this typecasting works,becoz when the format specifieris %d it is printing 1 but for %s it is not printing anything? why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = 1;
    char *c = (char*)&n;
    printf("%d %s",*c,c);
    if (*c)
        printf("LITTLE ENDIAN");
    else
        printf("BIG ENDIAN");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For cn=1, the string is made of characters `0x00`and `0x01` but neither of those is printable.  Try assigning `'A'` to n.

Answer (score 1):

The program you've provided is checking the endianness(the order in which a sequence of bytes is stored in computer memory) of the system by casting an unsigned int to a char*.
`printf("%d %s", *c, c);`attempts to print two values:

%d expects an int and prints the integer value at the memory location pointed to by c, which is 1.
The reason it prints "1" for %d is because it reads the first byte of the unsigned int where the value 1 is stored.

%s expects a null-terminated character array (string) and prints the string starting from the memory location pointed to by c. However, this is not guaranteed to be a valid string in memory, and it may not be null-terminated, resulting in unpredictable behavior. In C, printing a non-null-terminated character array with %s is undefined behavior.

The reason it doesn't print anything for %s is because the memory location pointed to by c is not guaranteed to be null-terminated or to contain a valid string. Printing it as a string with %s is undefined behavior and could lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

The "%s" in printf() doesn't print properly because the ASCII value for decimal 1 is in the unprintable range.  Printable characters don't begin until about 32 decimal which is for the white space character.  After that, 33 decimal is for the exclamation mark (!), and so on.   Please consult [this chart](https://www.ascii-code.com/characters/printable-characters) for more info.

Here is an alternative solution for illustrating what you wanted/intended -- it is *your* code with very minor changes, which is generally my preferred approach for answers on stackoverflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = '!', i=0;
    char *c = (char*)&n;

    printf("%s\n", c);

    while(i < sizeof(int))
        printf("%d ", c[i++] );
        
    if (*c)
        printf("\nLITTLE ENDIAN");
    else
        printf("\nBIG ENDIAN");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:  -- runnable code is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xb6cGr5hK)

```
!
33 0 0 0 
LITTLE ENDIAN
```